# Presta shop ps_product_lang table, how to copy data from lang 2 to lang 1 missing entries

Tags: mysql, prestashop-1.6

PrestaShop search does not work properly if you don't have english descriptions completed.
I want to copy the descriprions and the rest data in table "ps_product_lang"
from language id 2 to language id 1.
I run the following query in database:

```
INSERT INTO ps_product_lang (id_product, description, description_short, link_rewrite, meta_description, meta_keywords, meta_title, name, available_now, available_later)
SELECT  id_product, 1, description, description_short
FROM    ps_product_lang
WHERE   id_lang = 2;
```

and get an error:
"#1136 - Column count doesn't match value count at row 1"

Could you please let me know where is my mistake?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You don't have enough values (`id_product, 1, description, description_short`) from `SELECT` to insert into columns `id_product, description, description_short, link_rewrite, meta_description, meta_keywords, meta_title, name, available_now, available_later`. You are missing `link_rewrite, meta_title` etc.

Also, that `1` in `SELECT` is probably `id_lang` that you need to include in `INSERT INTO` clause.

Edited -- added INSERT statement:

```
INSERT INTO ps_product_lang 
            (id_product, 
             id_lang, 
             description, 
             description_short, 
             link_rewrite, 
             meta_description, 
             meta_keywords, 
             meta_title, 
             name, 
             available_now, 
             available_later) 
SELECT id_product, 
       1 AS id_lang,/* Number value as column alias */ 
       description, 
       description_short, 
       link_rewrite, 
       meta_description, 
       meta_keywords, 
       meta_title, 
       name, 
       available_now, 
       available_later 
FROM   ps_product_lang 
WHERE  id_lang = 2;
```

I didn't try it, but I think it should be pretty close.

Comment: Tried a few variations based on your suggestions and I get syntax errors. Not really "fluent" in mysql; could you suggest a query that might work? Thanks!

Comment: This time the error is: #1062 - Duplicate entry '1-1-1' for key 'PRIMARY'

Comment: You already have a record with `id_lang` equal to 1. Maybe you entered it through Prestashop back end. Anyway, before you run my query from the answer, delete all existing products with  `id_lang` equal to 1: ```DELETE FROM `ps_product_lang` WHERE `id_lang` = 1```.